# Convert Qt image to image in Open CV in Python

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, opencv

I have an image in Qt which I would like to process using OpenCV.So I need to convert the image to IpIImage format.I'm working on Python in Ubuntu.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a python expert, but [this link could help you](http://matthewshotton.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/python-opencv-iplimage-to-pyqt-qimage/), it provides the reverse function you need, so I guess it's possible from that to make your conversion.